# Navigate to page(s) dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, navigation, state

In my first ASP.NET page (homepage), user answers a number of questions which determines which page(s) they will go to when they click on 'Next'.

E.g. if the following table results from the user input:

```
PageID Parameter
1      16
2      1
3      20
```

Then it tells the system that there are 3 pages to navigate to.

From the homepage, when user clicks on Next, it goes to the page with PageID = 1 (one particular aspx page) passing the parameter 16.

At the end of that page, clicking on the Next button takes user to page with PageID = 2 passing parameter 1, and then again, on click of Next button again user goes to pageID = 3 with parameter 20.

Finally, on click on Next on this last page, it leads to a final end page.

I am unsure how to design/code such dynamic page navigation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could have your custom Route definition by inheriting `RouteBase` class.

An example -

```
public class ParameterizedRoute : RouteBase
{
    const Dictionary<string,int> CustomParameters = new Dictionary<string,int> {{"1",16},{"2",1},{"3",20} };
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Datasheet");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", datasheetUrl.Action);
        var pageId = httpContext.Request.QueryString["PageId"].ToString();
        var param = CustomParameters[pageId];
        routeData.Values.Add("PageId", pageId);
        routeData.Values.Add("Parameter", param);
        return routeData;
    }
}
```

Here, I assume that your `PageId` comes in via `QueryString` and use `RouteData` to pass values.

In your `global.asax.cs`'s `Application_Start`, you could add it like

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add("CustomRoutes", new ParameterizedRoute());
```

In `ParameterizedRoute`, I've used a dictionary, you could add any other source as per your case.